# how to disable database configuration in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

The new app I'm working on is using Symfony2. There is no database connection to use. Instead it's build upon many web service calls. Under Symfony/app/config, I would like to remove all database_* entries but when I do that, I get a

```
ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_driver"
```

The error is obvious. But how do I decouple and remove the database configs from the app itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove DoctrineBundle initialisation from your AppKernel and `doctrine` configuration from your `app/config/config*.yml` files. It registers doctrine configuration in the container. That's why container complains if you try removing the parameters (bundle is enabled and looks for those parameters).

In latest versions of Symfony you'll also need to remove the doctrine channel from monolog configuration in `config_dev.yml` (remove the `channels: ["doctrine"]` line).

Comment: I also had to comment/remove the line "channels: ["doctrine"]" in monolog configuration of config_dev.yml

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 is integrated with Doctrine2 by default. You cannnot remove the configuration, unless you set another integration bundle.

It would be effortless if you simply leave these fields empty. A connection to the database would be made only when the application requires it, which, in your case, should not happen.

Comment: That's not true. You don't have to use Doctrine and it's possible to disable it.

Comment: Why is that? There's no harm in disabling Doctrine. If you use annotation you'd need to keep doctrine-common but that's not the same as dbal/orm.

Comment: Just a clarification. These days you'd need to enable doctrine/annotation instead of doctrine/common to add support for annotations.

Comment: By default at first time, doctrine tries to connect to database. If you disable doctrine from AppKernel and remove doctrine config declaration it will throws an monolog error because it's binded with doctrine. You can't disable unless you change extension and monolog bundle.

Comment: This is simply not true. Doctrine can be safely disabled. All you have to do is to clear cache after doing so.