# Symfony2 Doctrine: How to disable mysql connection?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Symfony2 for projects that doesn't use mysql at all, and mysql is not installed on my server.

In `parameters.yml` I left everything with default values.

Now every time I delete the cache, **on first page refresh** I get `500` error and in `error.log` I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server ...
```

but after I refresh the page everything works fine.

I heard that doctrine is not only ORM and is tightly connected with symfony so I can't disable/remove it.

All I want is to disable the mysql connection and get rid of that error.

Comment: Did You try to remove Doctrine from composer.json `"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev"` and `"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*"`

Comment: You can also just remove the lines from your parameters file

Comment: @JasonRoman if I remove the lines from the parameters file I get `You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_driver"`

Comment: Remove the `doctrine` section of app/config/config.yml as well

Comment: I tried this before and tried now again, on `cache:clear` I get two errors 1. `[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                  
  Monolog configuration error: The logging channel "doctrine" assigned to the "console_very_verbose" handler does not exist.` 2. `[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
  The service definition "monolog.logger.doctrine" does not exist.`

Comment: I thought there is a special parameter for that _(to disable mysql connection)_ or in docs may be something about that, without doing weird tweaks. Why symfony is forcing me to use _(mysql)_ doctrine database connection?

Comment: Look in `app/config/config_dev.yml` and remove lines that reference Doctrine, like `channels: ["!doctrine"]` and `channels: ["doctrine"]`

Comment: @JasonRoman I have none of that. I searched all files in `app/config/` and the only occurrence is in `app/config/config.yml` where is `doctrine:
    dbal:` (that I tried to remove before without success)

Comment: what version of Symfony are you running?  remove that the `doctrine:` references as well

Comment: @JasonRoman I installed today the latest symfony 2.6. I commented everything including `doctrine:`

Comment: So is it all working then?  If not, what's the error you are getting now

Comment: I wrote the error in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828416/symfony2-doctrine-how-to-disable-mysql-connection#comment44063221_27828416) Here is a screencast http://i.imgur.com/F5XmvEq.gif

Comment: right, there is still doctrine configuration information in monolog that needs to be removed.

Comment: I don't want to go that far.. To do this every time I install symfony is inconvenient. It will be better a simple config/parameter change.

Comment: Have you removed the bundle from the appkernel.php files?

Comment: It works. My fault, I had two installations and the first one didn't had the `channels: ["!doctrine"]` parameter in `config_dev.yml`, but I thought I have opened the file from the second installation... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also remove the doctrine initialisation from your AppKernel, and the doctrine configuration from your app/config/config.yml files, as seen on configuration from your app/config/config.yml, as seen on this thread : [how to disable database configuration in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091299/how-to-disable-database-configuration-in-symfony2)

Comment: Both this solution and @JasonRoman (from comments above) works. It was my fault that I had two installations and didn't edit the right files.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed in `app/config/parameters.yml` the driver from mysql to sqlite and the error is not happening anymore.

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_sqlite
```